# Elasticsearch Semantic search with facet, filter and boost

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, facet, embedding

I am implementing according to https://dev.to/mmoutih/semantic-search-with-openai-springboot-vaadin-elasticsearch-4lhg tutorial and it works for me.
I want to add facet, filter and boost in query.

my data object may look like htis

```
@Document(
    indexName="posts"
)
@ToString
public class Post {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String title;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String content;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String color;// e.g. red, blue, green

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String size;//e.g XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL

    @Field(type = FieldType.Dense_Vector, dims = 1536, index = true)
    private Vector<Double> embedding;

    public Post(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

How should I add this in query which currently looks like this

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Post, String>{

    @Query("{" +
            "    \"script_score\": {" +
            "       \"query\": {\"match_all\": {}}," +
            "       \"script\": {"+
            "           \"source\": \"cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'embedding') +0.1\","+
            "           \"params\": {\"queryVector\": ?0}"+
            "       }"+
            "   }"+
            "}")
    List<Post> findBySimilar( String content);
}
```

I tried lik

```
public interface PostRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Post, String> {

    @Query("{" +
            "    \"bool\": {" +
            "        \"must\": {" +
            "            \"script_score\": {" +
            "                \"query\": {" +
            "                    \"match_all\": {}" +
            "                }," +
            "                \"script\": {" +
            "                    \"source\": \"cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'embedding') + 0.1\"," +
            "                    \"params\": {" +
            "                        \"queryVector\": ?0" +
            "                    }" +
            "                }" +
            "            }" +
            "        }," +
            "        \"filter\": {" +
            "            \"term\": {" +
            "                \"color\": \"red\"" + // Replace with the color you want to filter by
            "            }" +
            "        }," +
            "        \"boost\": 1.2" +
            "    }" +
            "}")
    List<Post> findBySimilar(String content);
}
```

without success

Comment: The query parameter `?0` should be a dense vector, not a String

Comment: Did you manage to get the Boost to work?